# How to ignore white spaces input stream in operator overload >>

Tags: c++, overloading

Currently my overloaded `operator>>` function takes the input `[4: 1 2 3 4 ]` and works fine. But how can I ignore any number of white spaces so that it can accept `[ 4  : 1 2 3 4 ]` , i.e any number of white spaces before the input?

```
istream& operator>>( istream & stream, my_vector & vector_a ) {
    string token2;

    int vec_size;
    vector<double> temp_vec;

    bool push = false;

    while (stream >> token2) {
        if (token2[0] == '[' && token2[2] ==':') {
            push = true;
        }

        if (token2 == "]") {
            break;
        }
        else if(!(token2[0] == '[' && token2[2] ==':')) {
            stream.setstate(ios::badbit);
        }

        if(push) {
            istringstream str(token2);
            double v;
            if (str >> v)
                temp_vec.push_back(v);
            vector_a.set_data(temp_vec);
        }
    }

    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
stream >> std::ws;
```

Extracts as many whitespace characters as possible from the current position in the input sequence. The extraction stops as soon as a non-whitespace character is found. These whitespace characters extracted are not stored in any variable.

Note that this will skip whitespace even if the `skipws` flag was previously `unsetf` in the source stream, so you should do it anyways.

Comment: I've put stream >> token2 >> std::ws in my while loop condition but it still doesn't seem to work. I assume that is what you meant?

Comment: @cody: Your problem is not with whitespace but with the understanding of what a 'token' is. Instead of reading a string, read a `char` (followed by `ws`), then an `int` (followed by `ws`) and then another `char`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do something on this order:

```
stream.setf(std::skipws);

char open_bracket, close_bracket, colon;

unsigned num_items, temp_item;

stream >> open_bracket;
stream >> num_items;
stream >> colon;

for (int i=0; i<num_items; i++) {
    stream >> temp_item;
    temp_vec.push_back(temp_item);
}

stream >> close_bracket;

if (open_bracket != '[' || close_bracket != ']' || colon != ':')
    stream.setstate(ios::failbit);
```

Note that the bit to set for a failed conversion is failbit, not badbit. badbit is intended for things like a failed attempt at reading from the disk.

Comment: And now you've changed the state of the `skipws` flag explicitly set by the user. At least do an attempt to restore it to its original value.

Comment: @K-ballo : And as usual, there's a Boost library for that :-] [boost.io state savers](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html)