# trying to read and store data from a file where there are multiple spaces between each intended data

Tags: c++, fstream

Here's a simple code on how I read and store the data. I have a text file and inside the text file are the data that I want to pass to both `number` and `text`. The code runs fine if the text file contains text such as `2 HelloWorld1`, **2** is stored into `number` and **HelloWorld1** is stored into `text`.

But what if the text in the txt file is as such, `2 Hello World 1` where there are spaces between Hello, World and 1? My question is would it be possible for **2** to be stored in `number` and **Hello World 1** to be stored in `text`. i understand that because of the empty spaces and as such only **2** and **Hello** and stored in both `number` and `text` respectively. Is there a way to overcome this?

```
using namespace std;
int main(){

    ifstream theFile("key.txt");

    int number;
    string text;

    while(theFile>>number>>text){
        cout<<number<<" and "<<text<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stream operator `>>` splits incoming values based on whitespaces. If you need any other parsing, you need to either parse the file yourself or use some library (you can for example use `boost::spirit`). EDIT: also see for example this answer for more ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959688/how-to-ignore-white-spaces-input-stream-in-operator-overload .

Comment: What is your actual task? Usually, when you parse a format, there are some standards for a format. You'd work with that. Other than that, take a look at `std::ifstream::get`.

Comment: The best way is to design your storage format so that it's easy to read.

Comment: Note that C++ streams are quite slow. If you need to parse a large amount of simple data, do hand parse it with regex or stoa().

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck with the default stream operator >> (if that is indeed your case).

### 1: Know the format

The way forward is to **know the format** which judging from your post you are somewhat uncertain about.

### 2: Use the best tools for the job

After that you **choose the right tool for the job**. That could involve: std::getline and handpassing, perhaps using a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (in your case, fairly simply ones), boost::spirit, tokenization techniques, boost::string_algo, lex/bison and more.
I would add that customizing stream operator functionality (while possible) is rarely the straightforward choice.

### 3: Design your format to match

As an alternative to knowing the format, if you can design it, so much the better. If you have record style format, an easy way to handle strings with spaces is to put the string last - then put each record on a line. That way you may first look over each line using eg. `std::getline` and then just use stream operators for the rest - knowing the string will come last. Other delimiters (than linefeed) is certainly doable as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an example to the very good answer of @darune.

It all depends on the input format.

Assuming that your line starts with a number and then ends with a string, you can use the following approach:

1. First read a number with extractor operator >>
2. Use getline to read the rest

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

std::istringstream testData (
R"#(1   data1
2 data2 data3 
3 data    4
)#");


int main()
{
    // Definition of variables
    int number{};
    std::string str{};

    // Read file
    // Read the number
    while (testData >> number)
    {
        // Read the rest of the line in a string
        getline(testData, str);
        // Remove leading and trailing spaces
        str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex("^ +| +$|( ) +"), "$1");
        // Show result
        std::cout << number << ' ' <<str << '\n';
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1 data1
2 data2 data3
3 data    4
```

But as said, it strongly depends on the input format